# how to fit a linear regression to days over wp

Tags: r, linear-regression

How would I fit a linear regression line over days of time to a subset of days 20 to 64 for only two of my treatments. I have to subset from my main data but it wont let me choose a range of days and also by treatments I have. I used this code below but it only plots the one day and provides the a and b.
Basically I need to plot the regression line to see when it intersects -2MPa.

```
##fitting a linear line on graph to find TLP####
##subset to biochar and no biochar in drought##
dat_line<-subset(dat, days > 20 & days < 64)
line_BD<-subset(dat_line,drought=="drought" & treatment=="biochar")
line_NBD<-subset(dat_line, drought=="drought" & treatment=="no biochar")

lm(days~wp_Mpa, data=line_BD)
abline(a=28.243, b=-1.919)

lm(days~wp_Mpa, data=line_NBD)
abline(a=20.83, b=-2.80)
```

tried the code above, looking on other stack overflow

```
one treatment data set

   treatment drought days  N    mean_wp        sd        se
1    biochar drought    0 12 -0.5784129 0.6308831 0.1821203
2    biochar drought    1  8 -1.4366956 0.9335251 0.3300510
3    biochar drought    3  7 -2.0759137 1.0529204 0.3979665
4    biochar drought    8  6 -1.7999920 0.5245320 0.2141393
5    biochar drought   11  5 -1.9390823 0.9582212 0.4285295
6    biochar drought   17 10 -1.3570956 0.6604088 0.2088396
7    biochar drought   21  6 -1.3617151 1.8131385 0.7402107
8    biochar drought   23  3 -1.6917443 0.4362822 0.2518876
9    biochar drought   29  3 -1.8935309 0.7635187 0.4408178
10   biochar drought   36  6 -3.0623077 1.2009647 0.4902918
11   biochar drought   43 10 -3.4186978 2.7052291 0.8554686
12   biochar drought   64 15 -4.4986011 1.8798342 0.4853711
```

data output:
Call:
lm(formula = days ~ wp_Mpa, data = line_BD)

```
Coefficients:
(Intercept)       wp_Mpa  
     28.243       -1.919
```

Comment: We need a sample of your data using `dput()` and the output that the `lm()` calls produced. With no `plot()` command, they should have generated error messages.

Comment: Can you clarify your model?  "wp_Mpa" is not a column in the sample data provided.   Also are you sure  "days" is the dependent variable?

Comment: wp_Mpa is the parameter I am trying to run the line through and it needs to be fi to days over time